# Php получить список входящих писем с SMTP сервера?

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

Пересылка писем происходит через SMTP сервер. Хотелось бы понять каким образом можно получить список входящих/исходящих сообщений для конкретного email-а на php?

Comment: [PHP IMAP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.imap.php)

Comment: @AndreyMihalev спасибо) Если оформите как ответ - отмечу)